# Starting Apache mesos in daemon mode

Tags: ansible, mesos

Does anyone know where the init scripts for mesos 1.3.0 are?
(I've built mesos from source on ubuntu 16.0)

I'm starting mesos like the following currently, via ansible:

```
/opt/mesos/build/bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=`hostname -i` --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
```

However, the moment Ansible disconnects from the terminal, mesos process dies. So it seems this way of starting mesos is not compatible with a remote, automated installation.

I've tried preceding the command with nohup, and backgrounding it as well as in this script (to no avail):

````
#!/bin/bash
# Start the mesos slave 
# Start Mesos master (ensure work directory exists and has proper  permissions).
 nohup /opt/mesos/build/bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=`cat    /tmp/master.ip`:5050 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos &```
````

It only seems to work when I run it by hand, logged on to a terminal, and starting it via ansible doesn't result in the process staying running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mesos does not come with daemon init scripts. You need to prepare them by youself.

You can take a look at [mesosphere/mesos-deb-packaging](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-deb-packaging/blob/master/init/master.init)

For example systemd script could look like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mesos Master
After=network.target
Wants=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mesos-init-wrapper master
Restart=always
RestartSec=20
LimitNOFILE=16384

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

*Example for agent configuration.*
For me with Ubuntu/init.d, worked the following in a simplest form, sure there is room for optimization:

Create an executable file, `/etc/init.d/mesos`

Use the following contents:

```
#! /bin/sh

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:             mesos
# Default-Start:        2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:         0 1 6
# Short-Description:    Apache Mesos 1.5.0
### END INIT INFO

set -e

case "$1" in
  start)
       /opt/mesos/bin/mesos-agent.sh --master=<YOUR_MASTER_HOST>:5050 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos &  > /var/log/mesos 2>&1
       ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Start with:
`service mesos start`